# tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) function not being called when trying to retrieve data from Firebase

Tags: swift, uitableview, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm new to Stack Overflow so please be gentle!

I'm designing an app that retrieves objects from firebase and displays them in fire base.

I configure firebase here:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    FIRApp.configure()
    FIRDatabase.database().persistenceEnabled = true
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    return true
}
```

However, I'm finding when I run the app, I just get a blank white screen. After some debugging, I realised it's because the TableView (cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) block of code isn't being reached:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ItemCell", for: indexPath)
let BUCSItem = items[indexPath.row]
   cell.textLabel?.text = BUCSItem.name
        print("should show bucs")
        return cell    
   }
```

I have the other required tableView method:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return items.count
}
```

Here is my viewDidLoad:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {   
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference(withPath: "BUCS-items")
    tableView.allowsMultipleSelectionDuringEditing = false

    ref.queryOrdered(byChild: "BUCSgoals").observe(.value, with: { snapshot in
        var newItems: [BUCSItem] = []
        for child in snapshot.children {
            if let snapshot = child as? FIRDataSnapshot,
                let BUCSItem = BUCSItem(snapshot: snapshot) {
                newItems.append(BUCSItem)
            }
        }
        self.items = newItems

        self.tableView.reloadData()
    })

}
```

But heres the weird part. When I disconnect form the internet, it works perfectly fine, and the items appear in the table as they're meant to. It's only when connected to the internet that they don't display.

Here's what it looks like when disconnected:
When connected its the same, but the names aren't appearing in the table.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a quick update convert

```
ref.queryOrdered(byChild: "BUCSgoals").observe(.value
```

to

```
ref.queryOrdered(byChild: "BUCSgoals").observeSingleEvent(.value
```